# How to fix the error "%%i was unexpected at this time" in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am trying to download a few files from a FTP server and place them in different folders, based on their file names.

Using:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%i IN (%binpath%inputfilelist.txt) DO ECHO. get %%i >> %binpath%unixftp_get1.txt
```

I am getting the error:

> %%i was unexpected at this time

I have checked the files in `inputfilelist.txt`, there are `2` files available.

```
REM **********************Determine input file count*******************************************

SET target=TXT
CHDIR /d %binpath%
find /c  "%target%" < %binpath%inputfilelist.txt >  %binpath%inputfilecount.txt 
SET /p inputfile_cnt=<%binpath%inputfilecount.txt

IF %inputfile_cnt%!==!0 GOTO PROCEED

IF %inputfile_cnt%==0 GOTO END

:PROCEED

REM ******************** Dynamically create the ftp get commands file and download the files*************************
copy %binpath%unix_ftp.config %binpath%unixftp_get1.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%i IN (%binpath%inputfilelist.txt) DO ECHO. get %%i >> %binpath%unixftp_get1.txt

ECHO. bye >>  %binpath%unixftp_get1.txt

ftp -v -s:"%binpath%unixftp_get1.txt" %server% >> "%logpath%%ftp_log%"
```

Expected result is the file names say `abc.txt` needs to be appended in the file  `unixftp_get1.txt`.

Comment: This script will run inside the server windows 2008 R2 Standard edition.What command extensions should I need to enable?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl It does run on the server.The batch file is failing to get the files from the  %inputfilelist.txt" to %unixftp_get1.txt%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at this line:

```bat
IF %inputfile_cnt%!==!0 GOTO PROCEED
```

It will not `GOTO PROCEED` because your comparison is expecting **`#!`** to match **`!0`**, *(where `#` is the count of lines containing `TXT`)*, but it clearly never will.

To fix that you would generally use the following syntax:

```bat
IF NOT "%inputfile_cnt%"=="0" GOTO PROCEED
```

You would then change the line below it to read:

```bat
GOTO END
```

Here is a rewrite of your snippet, give it a try and provide feedback as necessary:

```bat
REM ************************ Determine input file count ************************
SET "target=TXT"
CD /D "%binpath%"

FOR %%A IN (logpath,ftp_log)DO IF NOT DEFINED %%A GOTO END

FOR %%A IN ("inputfilelist.txt","unix_ftp.config","%logpath%"
)DO IF NOT EXIST "%%~A" GOTO END

FOR /F %%A IN ('FIND /C "%target%"^<"inputfilelist.txt"'
)DO IF "%%A"=="0" GOTO END

:PROCEED
REM *** Dynamically create the ftp get commands file, and download the files ***
COPY /Y "unix_ftp.config" "unixftp_get1.txt"

(   FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ("inputfilelist.txt")DO ECHO get %%A
    ECHO bye
)>>"unixftp_get1.txt"

ftp -v -s:"unixftp_get1.txt" %server% >>"%logpath%%ftp_log%"
```